# Php convert string to the right type

Tags: php

I really looking for one function that can help me convert value like this (after var_dump):

string(2) "49" to  integer
or string(3) "1.2" to float.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690654/how-to-get-the-real-type-of-a-value-inside-string) doesn't work for me 
Thanks

Here is my code:
I simply have one Recursion function to check all elements of my array

```
            foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            {
                if(is_array($value))
                {
                    $this->__set_types($value);
                }
                if(is_numeric($value))
                {
                    echo getcorrectvariable($value);
                    $arr[$key] = settype($value, gettype_fromstring($value));
                    var_dump($arr);
                }
            }   

function gettype_fromstring($string){
    //  (c) José Moreira - Microdual (www.microdual.com)
    return gettype(getcorrectvariable($string));
}   
function getcorrectvariable($string){
    //  (c) José Moreira - Microdual (www.microdual.com)
    //      With the help of Svisstack (https://stackoverflow.com/users/283564/svisstack)

    /* FUNCTION FLOW */
    // *1. Remove unused spaces
    // *2. Check if it is empty, if yes, return blank string
    // *3. Check if it is numeric
    // *4. If numeric, this may be a integer or double, must compare this values.
    // *5. If string, try parse to bool.
    // *6. If not, this is string.

    $string=trim($string);
    if(empty($string)) return "";
    if(!preg_match("/[^0-9.]+/",$string)){
        if(preg_match("/[.]+/",$string)){
            return (double)$string;
        }else{
            return (int)$string;
        }
    }
    if($string=="true") return true;
    if($string=="false") return false;
    return (string)$string;
}
```

Here is one pice of my array (var_dump)

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "106"
      ["idMessageType"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["idClientSender"]=>
      string(2) "59"
      ["idClientRecipient"]=>
      string(2) "49"
      ["message"]=>
      string(5) "rwert"
      ["creationTimeStamp"]=>
      string(22) "2014-11-04 10:09:12+05"
      ["readingTimestamp"]=>
      NULL
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["isMessageActive"]=>
      string(1) "t"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "105"
      ["idMessageType"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["idClientSender"]=>
      string(2) "59"
      ["idClientRecipient"]=>
      string(2) "49"
      ["message"]=>
      string(7) "qwrqewr"
      ["creationTimeStamp"]=>
      string(22) "2014-11-04 10:08:56+05"
      ["readingTimestamp"]=>
      NULL
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["isMessageActive"]=>
      string(1) "t"
    }
    ["client"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "49"
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "а аАаВаИаЛб"
      ["surname"]=>
      string(14) "ааАбаИаПаОаВ"
      ["photoName"]=>
      string(50) "49.jpg                                            "
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work? What's the string and what's the type you get as a result? Can you add some code?

Comment: no but it must be way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

floatval or intval will do what you ask, separately.

If you want to retrieve the type... doesn´t make sense to me, but you could make a custom function using a regex... here:

```
function getTypedNumber($string)
{
$pattern = '/^(\d{1,3})((,)(\d{3}))*((\.)(\d{1,2}))?$|^(\d{1,3})((\.)(\d{3}))*((,)(\d{1,2}))?$/';
$replacement = '\1\8\4\11.\7\14';
$number = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement,$string);
if (is_numeric($number){
 if (strpos($number, ".") === false )  return intval($number);
 else return floatval($number);
}
else return false;
}
```

It will process number in the format 10.300,25 or 10,300.25 as well

**EDIT**

Forgot, that regex works assuming 2 decimal positions, it can be changed easily, if needed, but then it won´t process French/English Number style

Comment: wait but how i can know if it float or int?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was obvious when returning intval or floatval.... same function can be changed to return "float" or "int" instead of intval or floatval, so you can get the type.

Comment: your solution work with this condition
  if (!strpos($number, ".") === false )
  {
    return intval($number);
  }
  else 
  {
   return floatval($number);
  }

Comment: u sure?? what you posted means , if a dot found, return int, else return float, what sounds weird to me.

Comment: Thank you! i've editing your code and its work for me

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

```
intval("42") // -> 42
intval("53.4") // -> 53
floatval("53.4") // -> 53.4
```

Why not googling "php parse float" first?

Comment: A float will serve as an int too, so you can use `floatval` all the time (unless the type is explicitly said to be int).

Comment: I don't know type of my var

Comment: ^neither does php. Php does type jugling