# How to get primitive json request payload in Laravel 5?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, http-post

Let say that this is the payload of a request:

```
{name : 'John', age: 42}
```

You can get all paramters with `Request::all()`.

How do I get request payload correctyly if payload is a primitive type like `true` or `42`?

`Request::getContent()` receives them as strings, I want them to be in correct type as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `json_decode` to decode a raw json payload to an array:

```
Route::post('/request', function () {
    $payLoad = json_decode(request()->getContent(), true);

    dd($payLoad['name']);
});
```

And you should get

```
John
```

Or can use `json_decode` to decode your payload from a query parameter or post data:

```
Route::get('/primitive', function () {
    $payLoad = json_decode(request()->get('payload'));

    dd($payLoad);
});
```

Hitting:

```
http://app.dev/primitive?payload={%20%22name%22:%20%22John%22,%20%22age%22:%2042,%20%22male%22:%20true%20}
```

You should get

[image]

Comment: Payload is not a key value pair. Just a json value in the body of POST request. I can use `json_decode(request()->getContent())` then. Thanks

Comment: My solution here should work also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690654/how-to-get-the-real-type-of-a-value-inside-string