# Read user input and check data type

Tags: php

I've simple PHP script:

```
<?php
$input = readline();

echo gettype($input);
?>
```

It reads user input from the console. What I am trying to achieve is to get properly data type. At the moment $input is string type.

I need something like this:

```
Input    Output
 5       Integer
2.5      float
true     Boolean
```

I can't get any idea how to do it. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Thanks to @bcperth answer, I achieve this working code:

```
<?php
 while(true) {
 $input = readline();
 if($input == "END") return ;
  if(is_numeric($input)) {
      $sum = 0;
      $sum += $input;
       switch(gettype($sum)) {
           case "integer": $type = "integer"; break;
           case "double": $type = "floating point"; break;
       }
       echo "$input is $type type" . PHP_EOL;
  }
  if(strlen($input) == 1 && !is_numeric($input)) {
      echo "$input is character type" . PHP_EOL;
  } else if(strlen($input) > 1 && !is_numeric($input) && strtolower($input) != "true" && strtolower($input) != "false") {
      echo "$input is string type" . PHP_EOL;
  }  if(strtolower($input) == "true" || strtolower($input) == "false") {
      echo "$input is boolean type" . PHP_EOL;
  }
 }
?>
```

Also tried with `filter_var`, working well:

```
<?php
while(true) {
    $input = readline();
    if($input == "END") return;
      if(!empty($input)) {
        if(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === 0) {
        echo "$input is integer type" . PHP_EOL;
        } else if(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) || filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) === 0.0) {
        echo "$input is floating point type" . PHP_EOL;
        } else if(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) || strtolower($input) == "false") {
        echo "$input is boolean type" . PHP_EOL;
        } else if(strlen($input) == 1) {
        echo "$input is character type" . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
        echo "$input is string type" . PHP_EOL;
        }
      }
}

?>
```

Comment: User input will always be a string. You could use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to check if this string contains a number, but this does not differentiate between ints and floats.

Comment: [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) might also be worth a look, it would return true for an integer and false for a float, as the float would contain a decimal separator. On the other hand, all integers are also valid floats...

Comment: @KarstenKoop `ctype_digit()` won't work on negative numbers

Comment: a simple search away from objective :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690654/how-to-get-the-real-type-of-a-value-inside-string

Comment: @VayuDev the answer given there by bcperth is far more efficient that the poor one in the question you've linked

Comment: I considered a regex at first glance, but decided was easier to get PHP to print out what it already knows! :-). Hurrah for dynamic typing. Otherwise VayuDev is correct that the question looks a lot like a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to employ a few strategies as below for simple types.

1. test if numeric using is_numeric().
2. if numeric then add it to zero and gettype() the result
3. if not numeric then compare to "true" and "false"
4. if not "true" or "false" then its a string

Here is a working start that shows how to go about it.

```
<?php
$input = readline();

if (is_numeric($input)){
    $sum =0;
    $sum += $input;
    echo gettype($sum);
}
else {
    if ($input== "true" or $input == "false"){
        echo "boolean";
    }
    else {
        echo "string";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer with your "logical" help, now it's working as I expected. :)