# Laravel 6 Form Array $request->input() doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have this array of prices, like so:

```html
<input type="input" id="prices[type][1]" name="prices[type][1]">
<input type="input" id="prices[type][2]" name="prices[type][2]">
```

I send this data via a post request (JSON: Yes, the `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`) and expected to get an array when I use `$request->input('prices')` but that doesn't really happen. Also tried `$request->get('prices')`.

When I do `$request->all()` I do get all the data I submitted:

[image: dumps of the different request methods]

JS Used to make request:

```js
const response = await fetch(this.action, {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.$page.token,
  },
  body: this.formData(),
});

const body = await response.json();
```

`this.formData()`:

```js
formData(): Object {
  const formData = new FormData(this.$el);

  return JSON.stringify(Array.from(formData.entries()).reduce((memo, pair) => ({
    ...memo,
    [pair[0]]: pair[1],
  }), {}));
},
```

Does anyone have an idea on where it might go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it looks like the array is broken even if you do `all()` as I don't see the `type` key in the array.

Try this instead:

```
dd(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));
```

As it is JSON so you will need to get the body and convert it into an array.

Comment: Oh, my bad I blacked out the type, I do get the type. But I tried the `json_decode` already, it gives the same result as `$request->all()`

Comment: @RobinB on the `$request->getContent()` or on `$request->all()`?

Comment: Also you can use `JSON.stringify` before you post it to the controller. Or please share your AJAX code so you can get better help.

Comment: On the `$request->getContent()`, I'm using `JSON.stringify()` in the JS, I'll update my answer with the JS

Comment: Hm, and can you check the content from the request body in the network tab of your browser, how does it look like? And check on some of the online tools if it is a valid JSON?

Comment: Yep, it's valid JSON

Comment: So your JSON structure is wrong my friend. It has to do something with this part `Array.from(formData.entries()).reduce((memo, pair) => ({
    ...memo,
    [pair[0]]: pair[1],
  }), {})`

Comment: Turns out that was indeed the case, the nested values didn't really work. Thanks for your quick responses!

Comment: @RobinB you can show appreciation by voting on the answer, or marking the answer as solution which will build my reputation on SO :)
Happy to help.

Comment: Here is my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690654/how-to-get-the-real-type-of-a-value-inside-string

I created a middleware that transforms data types to their correct ones, not stringified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$prices_array = $request->only('prices');
```

Or:

```
$no_prices_array = $request->except('prices');
```

That way you can filter a request by field, and access them.